# Trash Folder is Empty but shows Emails

Tags: email, pop3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running the Lollipop OS.  My ISP is Verizon and my email is run on MS Outlook.  Since the Lollipop upgrade, the Trash Folder indicates that I have (for example) 35 emails, but when I open the folder is is correctly empty.  The only fix I've read is to delete my email account and then reinstall it.  I tried this but it only worked for about a day, and then my empty Trash Folder once again started indicating that the folder is filling up.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: What email app are you using?  I'd suggest using a different one.  This issue plagued Samsung's e-mail app as far back as Android 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue, seems the only way to reset it, is to delete the acct. on your phone and then set it up again, I've started to observe what I am doing to contribute to this, and discovered if I delete a message without opening it, it causes the numbers to raise, If I open each email before deleting it, the trash will not display a number

Comment: Thanks.  I will try your suggestion to open before deleting.  Many thanks!